# Create and get a cookie in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookies

What I am looking to achieve is that when a user comes to my site they immediately encounter a pop up (or a landing page) that asks, are you a man or a woman or other (choose x or y or z). They pick and click the link, then once they choose they go to that part of the site (and no it isn't a adult site ;). A cookie then remembers their choice and each time they return they are automatically redirected to their choice.

So basically we need the ability to set a cookie based on their choice (via link or form button) and then when they return to the homepage get that cookie and redirect.

I've seen some questions and answers that are close but just not quite there with this scenario and I end up confused.
What do you think? Doable? Please help and thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much of your architecture, I came up with the following:

This code should be called after the user has made the choice:

```
//´choice´ contains the value of what the user chose
//Setting the cookie:
document.cookie="gender="+ choice +"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2029 12:00:00 UTC";
//Redirect the user after the cookie has been set:
document.location.href = "http://yoursite.com/";
```

Take a look how cookies are defined in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Then in PHP code you may read what cookies are set when the user loads your site:

```
if($_COOKIE["gender"] === "x"){
//Do some x stuff
} else if($_COOKIE["gender"] === "y") {
//Do some y stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rnli. I'm trying out your solution today and will get back to you. Gratitude.